# replacing characters from a string to another python

Tags: python, string

i have 2 sample DNA strings here:

```
text = "AANGCTWCAAGGT"
text1= "AAGTTTCG"
```

text contains ambiguous nucleotides 'N' and 'W' since they are not 'AGCT'(note: any nucleotide that is not 'AGCT' or 'agct' is considered ambiguous)
So that's the purpose of text1, it doesn't contain any ambiguous nucleotide, i would like to compare text and text1 and replace the ambiguous nucleotides from text with text1.  so  'N' = 'G' and 'W' = 'C' based on their positions.

my code:

```
text = "AANGCTWCAAGGT"
text1= "AAGTTTCG"
m = len(text)
n = len(text1)
for j in range(n)[1:]:
if 'A' not in text[j] and 'G' not in text[j]and 'C' not in text[j]and 'T' not in text[j]and 'a' not in text[j]and 'g' not in text[j]and 'c' not in text[j]and 't' not in text[j]:
    newtext = text.replace(text[j], text1[j])
    print(newtext)
```

output:

```
In[89]:runfile('C:/Users/..code')
AAGGCTWCAAGGT
AANGCTCCAAGGT
```

desired output:

```
AAGGCTCCAAGGT
```

i think i'm missing something, maybe other loop? I am not sure how i can fix the code so that it combines the replacements into the final output.

Comment: For one thing (and this may very well be a transcription error when you posted the question), but your loop doesn't do anything. Was the `if` supposed to be in the loop?

Comment: *so 'N' = 'G' and 'W' = 'C'*  could you clarify the logic here?

Comment: @ Linuxios  the if loop is supposed to tell whether  a nucleotide is ambiguous, my actual DNA sequences contain many more ambiguous nucleotides other than just 'NW'

Comment: @wim from text and text1 comparison, the 'N' from text should be 'G' from text1, the 'W' from text should be 'C' from text1.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but *why*?  Is it because they are at the same position?  text1 is shorter than text, so this seems fragile

Comment: @ wim please see my edit. yes because they are the same position, that's the purpose of text1, it doesn't contain ambiguou nucleotide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using text and not newtext when doing your replace. So newtext has its changes thrown away whenever you are doing a replace. You need to use newtext each time you do a replace. Or you need to allow in-place editing. For example:

```
text = "AANGCTWCAAGGT"
t_list = [c for c in text]
text1= "AAGTTTCG"
m = len(text)
n = len(text1)
for j in range(1, n):
    if 'A' not in text[j] and 'G' not in text[j]and 'C' not in text[j] and 'T' not in text[j] and 'a' not in text[j]and 'g' not in text[j]and 'c' not in text[j]and 't' not in text[j]:
        t_list[j] = text1[j]

print("".join(t_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
text = "AANGCTWCAAGGT"
text1= "AAGTTTCG"

print ''.join(c if c.lower() in 'agct' else text1[i] for i,c in enumerate(text))

>> AAGGCTCCAAGGT
```

Comment: hi @yurib  the above are only sample strings, the actual strings contains ambiguous nucleotides other than 'NW'

Comment: @Jessica isn't easy to adjust this to work for other 'nucleotides'? changing `'NW'` to include everything else?

Comment: @ yurib they are always different, i have no way to tell

Comment: @ yurib it would be easier to just say when a nucleotide is not equal to 'AGCTagct'

Comment: @Jessica sorry but if you have no way to tell, how would we?

Comment: @Jessica you need to explain what makes a nucleotide ambiguous and how you choose it's replacement from the other string

Comment: @ yurib please see my edit, any usually in DNA sequences, any nucleotide that's not 'AGCT' or 'agct' is considered ambiguous

Comment: @ yurib thanks but my actual files has 8 lines per sequence and the situation is not as simple as what i put up here, so i prefer loops so i can later on add in new code.

Comment: @Jessica you will only get answers for what you ask, please explain all of the constraints.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand in the comments and the question, you would like something like that (same algorithm as yurib's answer, but in a loop):

```
text = "AANGCTWCAAGGT"
text1= "AAGTTTCG"

res = ""
for i,c in enumerate(text):
    if c.lower() in 'agct':
        res = res +c
    else:
        res = res + text1[i]
```

Comment: i may not understand the question entirely, but what happens in your code if there is an ambiguous (e.g 'N') beyond the length of text1. Seems like it might be an index error

Comment: @GarrettR You're right but that constraint was not specified in the question. From what I formulate understood, and as strange as it sounds, the ambiguous nucleotides happen to be only in the common part of both strings, or it would be impossible to formulate a result without ambiguous nucleotides, no? did I miss something?